# Developing web pages using razor c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

I copied the code from the Microsoft website and pasted it into a project created using the "web application" template ASP.NET Core", but this code does not work.
I couldn't insert the code itself. We are talking about programming a calculator for adding two numbers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project in visual studio using Razor pages, then add the code partition appropriate for each file. Follow this first to understand the concepts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio